# Autostart within Windows 8 Desktop App Certification Requirements

Tags: vb.net, windows-8

The Windows 8 Desktop (not Metro!) App Certification Requirements state

> 10.2 Your app must avoid starting automatically on startup.
>   For example, your app should not set any of the following;
>
> - Registry run keys HKLM and, or HKCU under
>     Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion
> - Registry run keys HKLM, and or HKCU under   Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\windows\CurrentVersion
> - Start Menu AllPrograms > STARTUP `

I agree that lots of autostart background processes are unneccessary and this should be avoided if possible, but some apps (like mine) sit in the system tray and the user explicitly wants them to auto-start on boot.

Is there anything that's allowed to make the app auto-start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Task Scheduler can be used to launch programs whenever a user logs on. However, I believe the team does not want *certified* apps to run automatically at all. Of course drivers  will run on startup, but those aren't certified apps. I would guess that screen readers and accessibility tools wouldn't be considered certified apps either, but I'll ask around.

Comment: Thanks, Jared! I hope that giving the user the *option* to automatically run an app (through the task scheduler or otherwise) will be allowed.